# Mobile Network Issues

Tags: android, websocket, wifi, 3g, 4g

I have written an application using websocket protocol. I want to ensure a persistent connection for my application. I have the phone vibrate when it has successfully connected to my server. Right now, it works whenever I make a connection through wi-fi, but whenever I turn the wi-fi off, connection fails over the 4g service. Moreover, if I then turn the wi-fi on, the phone vibrates. Are there special events that I have to handle to ensure connectivity over 4g/3g services?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ConnectivityManager?

Check this out: [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)